# den, den / den, welchen

Tags: pronoun

Welche Option klingt gebräuchlich?

> „Welchen Hund hasst du?“ „Ich hasse **den, den / den, welchen** du heute gesehen hast, als wir auf der Straße waren“.

Answer (score 1):

Das eigentliche Relativpronomen welcher/welche/welches wird in der Umgangssprache nicht verwendet, und auch in der Literatur ist es selten. Man findet es praktisch nur in umständlichen Gebrauchstexten, oder wenn sich zu viele bestimmte Artikel anhäufen.

Comment: Und nach meiner Beobachtung im Hochdeutsch einiger Menschen, deren Dialekt weit vom Hochdeutsch entfernt ist.